# Copy list from Sharepoint Online to another list

Tags: list, development, csom

I want to copy a list (as it is with the same properties/metadata) from  Sharepoint Online to another list in another tenant.

I want to also  copy all the properties and metadata of each item.

I'm using C# and CSOM

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is to save the list as a template with content and download the file, re-upload it as a template in the new destination

Comment: Can you please attach some details about how to sava list as a template and then upload it?

Comment: can i have code plz , and in case of library , i should save all file in my pc !!! is thre another solution?

Comment: this procedure is done via the interface

Comment: i want to do it via my application (windows form , c#)

Answer (score 0):

you may use SharePoint API and C# to do this and you may refer to the below link as a reference

[Part 1: Copy a SharePoint List Programmatically](http://geekswithblogs.net/AnneBougie/archive/2009/01/23/copy-a-sharepoint-list.aspx)

Here's the code:

```
// Instantiate web instances
SPSite sourceSite = new SPSite(@"http://SharePointServer:31001");
SPWeb sourceWeb = sourceSite.RootWeb;
SPSite destSite = new SPSite(@"http://SharePointServer:31002");
SPWeb destWeb = destSite.RootWeb;

// Get a reference to the source list
SPList sourceList = sourceWeb.GetList("/Lists/Announcements");

// if the list exists on the destination site, delete it
try
{
   SPList temp = destWeb.Lists[sourceList.Title];
   destWeb.Lists.Delete(temp.ID);
}
catch { }

// create new list on the destination web with same properties
Guid newListID = destWeb.Lists.Add(sourceList.Title, sourceList.Description,
                                   sourceList.BaseTemplate);
SPList destList = destWeb.Lists[newListID];

// copy items
foreach (SPListItem item in announcements.Items)
{
   SPListItem newDestItem = destList.Items.Add();
   foreach (SPField field in sourceList.Fields)
   {
      if (!field.ReadOnlyField)
      newDestItem[field.Id] = item[field.Id];
   }
   newDestItem.Update();
}

// set quicklaunch settings
destList.OnQuickLaunch = sourceList.OnQuickLaunch;
destList.Update();
```